# How do I modify real-time DB change to firestore code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

How do I modify the Realtime Database change to Firestore code?

Now, I am using this code to realize my function in real-time

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Saves").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            mySaves.add(snapshot.getKey());
        }
        readSaves();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});

private void readSaves() {
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                postList_saves.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    PostModel postModel = snapshot.getValue(PostModel.class);
                    for(String id : mySaves){
                        if(postModel.getPostid().equals(id)){
                            postList_saves.add(postModel);
                        }
                    }
                }
                myFotoAdapter_saves.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
}
```

my DB structure

[image]

I tried to modify this code

```
CollectionReference ref = db.collection("Saves");
        ref.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if(error != null){
                    return;
                }
                for(DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = dc.getDocument();
                    mySaves.add(documentSnapshot.getKey());
                }
                readSaves();
            }
        });

private void readSaves() {
db.collection("Posts").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    postList_saves.clear();
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list  = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot d : list){
                        PostModel post = d.toObject(PostModel.class);
                        postList_saves.add(post);
                    }
                    myFotoAdapter_saves.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.noData), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

But, it's has error `error: cannot find symbol mySaves.add(documentSnapshot.getKey());`

and cannot filter the data, I got all the posts not saved date.
I think I am not getting the key values.

How do I modify the code?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: @AlexMamo Sorry about it, I'd updated the context

Comment: And you want to get all document IDs and add them to the `mySaves` list?

Comment: "I got the fault" What error did you get?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, I need to get snapshot.getKey(), but I don't know how to get.

Comment: To be 100% sure, you want to get `02nf...wQ93`, `Ffwa...tgo2`, and so on, and add them to the list, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'd updated my context. `02nf...wQ93` is user ID, then `-Mjbj3zM2vr-zKaKNT9v` and `-MkllN0v3il1s85g4BT4` is POST ID. So I need to know which user save which post.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "So I need to know which user save which post." What do you mean by that?

Comment: @AlexMamo I mean, I need to show which articles the user has added to my favorites

Comment: So in your particular example, you only want to get the two values, `-Mjbj3zM2vr-zKaKNT9v` and `-MkllN0v3il1s85g4BT4` that exist under `VxY7...dSb2`, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, because I need to get the key then send to readsaves();

Comment: @AlexMamo I updated the context.

Comment: Ok, but only those values, not any other values, right?